# How to generate simple contract classes

Tags: c#, t4, datacontract

I have a c# application which exposes an API (through WebAPI or WCF) and a separate dll for the Contract. The contract dll is exposed by NuGet so that callers can use the contract objects when calling the application.

However, the contract classes are decorated with custom validation attributes, many of which have dependencies on repository dlls and such, which I do not want to include in the contract NuGet. I would essentially like to publish a simplified form of the contract, which I can receive instead and deserialize into the original contract object (using ValueInjecter if need be).

I was unable to find a solution for this out of the box, so I began writing a t4 transformation file to run through the contract assembly and create new, simplified classes without all the validation attributes. This became quite tedious and I am hoping that someone out there has a better solution. I find it hard to believe that I am the first person to run into this issue.

**Edit**: Thanks for the feedback. For now, the T4 that I wrote is working pretty well and just generates the simple classes that I need. What is nice is that although the caller is sending the simplified class, it is being deserialized into the original class.

I have included the code for the base .ttinclude file below:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text"#>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>

<#+
    private class DtoGenerator
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<System.Resources.ResourceManager> ResourceManager =
            new Lazy<System.Resources.ResourceManager>(
                () => new System.Resources.ResourceManager("System.Data.Entity.Design", typeof(MetadataItemCollectionFactory).Assembly), isThreadSafe: true);

        private readonly TextTransformation textTransform;
        private readonly EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager;
        private readonly ITextTemplatingEngineHost Host;

        public DtoGenerator(object textTransform, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host)
        {
            this.textTransform = textTransform as TextTransformation;
            this.fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(textTransform);
            this.Host = host;
        }
        public void Write(string text)
        {
            this.textTransform.Write(text);
        }

        public void Generate(string folderName, string assemblyName)
        {
            var inputAssembly = GetAssembly(folderName, assemblyName);

            if (inputAssembly == null)
            {
                Write("// No assembly found");
                return;
            }

            var classes = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
            var types = inputAssembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(o => o.GetType().Name == "GenerateDtoAttribute")) //This is a custom attribute that marks classes to be generated
                .ToList();

            if (!types.Any())
            {
                Write("// No types found");
                return;
            }
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var baseExtension = "";
                var baseClass = type.BaseType;
                if (baseClass != null && baseClass != typeof(object))
                {
                    baseExtension = @" : " + baseClass;
                }

                var currentClass = string.Concat(@"
namespace ", type.Namespace, @"
{
    public class ", type.Name, baseExtension, @"
    {
", WritePublicProperties(type), @"
    }
}");
                classes.Add(type, currentClass);
            }

            foreach (var @class in classes)
            {
                fileManager.StartNewFile(@class.Key.Name + ".cs");
                Write(GetHeader());
                Write(@class.Value);
            }

            fileManager.Process();
        }

        private Assembly GetAssembly(string folderName, string assemblyName)
        {
            var relativePathTemplate = string.Format(@"..\{0}\bin\{{0}}\{1}.dll", folderName, assemblyName);
            string debugPath,
                releasePath,
                debugRelativePath = string.Format(relativePathTemplate, "debug"),
                releaseRelativePath = string.Format(relativePathTemplate, "release");

            try
            {
                debugPath = Path.GetFullPath(Host.ResolvePath(debugRelativePath));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                debugPath = null;
            }
            try
            {
                releasePath = Path.GetFullPath(Host.ResolvePath(releaseRelativePath));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                releasePath = null;
            }

            if (debugPath == null && releasePath == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var debugDllDate = debugPath == null ? DateTime.MinValue : File.GetLastWriteTime(debugPath);
            var releaseDllDate = releasePath == null ? DateTime.MinValue : File.GetLastWriteTime(releasePath);

            var assemblyDllPath = debugDllDate > releaseDllDate ? debugPath : releasePath;
            if (assemblyDllPath == null) return null;
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyDllPath);

            return assembly;
        }

        private string GetHeader()
        {
            var header = string.Format(
                @"//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// {0}
//
// {1}
// {2}
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
                ResourceManager.Value.GetString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1", null),
                ResourceManager.Value.GetString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine2", null),
                ResourceManager.Value.GetString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine3", null));

            return header;
        }

        private string WritePublicProperties(Type type)
        {
            var properties =
                type.GetProperties()
                    .Where(
                        info => info.DeclaringType == type
                            && info.GetMethod != null && info.GetMethod.IsPublic
                            && info.SetMethod != null && info.SetMethod.IsPublic)
                    .ToList();

            var propertyStrings = (from propertyInfo in properties
                let typeString = GetTypeName(propertyInfo.PropertyType)
                select string.Concat(@"      public ", typeString, " ", propertyInfo.Name, @" { get; set; }")).ToList();

            return string.Join("\r\n", propertyStrings);
        }

        private string GetTypeName(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
                return type.ToString().Split('`')[0] + "<" + string.Join(", ", type.GetGenericArguments().Select(GetTypeName).ToArray()) + ">";

            return type.ToString();
        }
    }

    #>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similair kind of situation where I have models and I'm sending that model from a backoffice, over a servicebus, down to a frontoffice and website. What I do, is have 3 almost identical POCO classes, in 3 different namespaces.

Now, the model in the frontoffice has attributes from the `JSON.NET` namespace, that determine how it needs to be (de)serialized. 
The models in the servicebus namespace may have some additional properties like `iscached` or something. Similarly, the backend models have attributes used for validation upon persistence `[Required]` and things.

Obviously I don't want `JSON.NET` attributes on the models that I'm saving in the database, or servicebus. Neither do I want `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation` attributes in the frontend or servicebus. So I map the models for each layer to the namespace of the next layer ( depending on the direction of the data flow ).

Mapping is done with AutoMapper on each layer - this can be one-liners if the models are very much alike. So an incoming message from JSON is deserialized as a FrontOffice model, then translated to ServiceBus model ans placed on the bus. 
The BackOffice deserializes the ServiceBus model and maps it to a BackOffice model... Anyway - you get it.

You could maybe do the same kind of setup - where your NuGet library are very clean POCO libraries with almost no dependencies. You have a highly similair model layer behind it to which you map the incoming messages. Then you perform the rich validation on it that you want to do.

It seems like duplication but for me it works really well since we have decoupled models. This will - for instance - also decouple the ALM of the BackOffice from the FrontOffice ( as long as the mapping is still valid ). If you go with the T4 approach  - your API models are very tightly coupled to your other models, which might become a problem in the future.